# Android SDK Installation

Tags: android

Iam using Microsoft Windows 7 Home basic with 3 Gb Ram and 320 GB HDD. i want to install Android SDK. Is my configuration suitable for installation....Wat care i have to take while installation....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, your system is elligble for installing the android SDK. I also recommend that you install the NetBeans Java IDE. Found here: http://netbeans.org/

Comment: I suggest eclipse because there is an official plugin support from google and many developers use that plugin

Comment: you need both eclipse AND the sdk. you can use a different ide than eclipse but i do not recommend this at all. Google has done a very good job of integrating the sdk with eclipse and all of their examples use eclipse. NetBeans is popular, but eclipse is the industry standard for Java development.

Comment: Thx.friends. Wat i undersood is i have to install Eclipse first then JDK and finally Android SDK.....Would it be one GUI where i can develop my Android applications or three different GUIs one for each sdk,jdk and eclipse. I need to switch between all these? what would be hierarchy of my development?

Comment: While you certainly *can* use NetBeans,  I'd only recommend it if you're already a Netbeans user, or you're already familiar with Android development using Eclipse, the Android SDK, and the Android ADT plugin for Eclipse.  

It sounds like the original poster is not terribly familiar with either Android development, Java development, or java development tools in general.   In which case, it only makes sense for him/her to follow the path of least resistance and start with the Google recommended dev environment setup. At least initially.

Comment: Bob...wat you recommend then .I aim to develop a professional Android application.

Comment: Though not the best answer, I'm not sure why the downvotes are necessary. He answered the question correctly, as well as going to the point of making an additional recommendation that also works fine. Eclipse may be a better choice in this respect, but what part of this answer was incorrect? +1 for having an unappreciated (albeit correct) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is on [the official website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).